# Whats a better TDD flow for this problem?

Tags: tdd

I have a domain entity called a "Booking Window" that has a Start Date and End Date, and defines a period in which a Member can make a Booking.  The business is a mobile car wash, and Members can book a wash every 14 days.

I have a means of establishing the first Booking Window - at the point of the Member signing up.  Now I feel like the next most useful function is one that finds all Booking Windows closing "today" and makes new ones.

So I wrote a test like this (kinda pseudo coded)

```
test("nothing to do when no booking windows at all", async () => {
    const client = stubGraphQlClientContainingNothing()
    const clock = new FixedClock(new Date())
    const windows = await makeTodaysBookingWindows(client, clock)
    expect(windows).toHaveLength(0)
})
```

and my function was just

```
export async function makeTodaysBookingWindows(client: GraphQlClient, clock: Clock): Promise<BookingWindow[]> {
    return []

}
```

Then I decided I needed a test of the case that had bookings, but none ending today:

```
test("nothing to do when no booking windows end today", async () => {
    const client = stubGraphQlClientContaining(bookingWindowEnding(tomorrow()))
    const clock = new FixedClock(new Date())
    const windows = await makeTodaysBookingWindows(client, clock)
    expect(windows).toHaveLength(0)

})
```

and the same function implementation allowed this to pass.

Now I decided I need to do a real case, of one Booking Window ending today:

```
test("create a new booking window when one expires today", async () => {
    const client = stubGraphQlClientContaining(bookingWindowEnding(today()))
    const clock = new FixedClock(new Date())
    const windows = await makeTodaysBookingWindows(client, clock)
    expect(windows).toHaveLength(1)
    expect(window[0].startDate).toBe(today())
    expect(window[0].endDate).toBe(today() + 14 days)

})
```

and that forced me to make some production code.

Now I am left thinking, what next?  The code I wrote to make the above test pass does not loop, so I need to cover the case where there are many Booking Windows ending today, so I write this:

```
test("create a new booking window for every window ending today", async () => {
    const client = stubGraphQlClientContaining(bookingWindowEnding(today()), bookingWindowEnding(today()))
    const clock = new FixedClock(new Date())
    const windows = await makeTodaysBookingWindows(client, clock)
    expect(windows).toHaveLength(2)
    expect(window[0].startDate).toBe(today())
    expect(window[0].endDate).toBe(today() + 14 days)
    expect(window[1].startDate).toBe(today())
    expect(window[1].endDate).toBe(today() + 14 days)

})
```

Now I probably have the production function I need, but the "create a new booking window when one expires today" test case is now irrelevant, so I guess the right thing to do is remove it.

Anyway, thats enough to communicate my approach to this function.  It doesn't "feel" great, so I'd appreciate knowing how others would approach this.  Thanks!

**Edit #1**: part of the reason I did this using a graphql client is that I (maybe prematurely) worried about the fact that this can scale to thousands of Booking Windows.  So I wanted to do it as a query to fetch stuff, then a single mutation to apply change.  But maybe that is also misguided.

Comment: "It doesn't 'feel' great" - maybe, but that's because these tests are (if I understood you well) *deceptively* simple. The way you've set it up, your test headers don't quite describe exactly what is it that you're truly testing; i.e. you're not (only) testing that `makeTodaysBookingWindows` creates a new window for every that ends today, you're more specifically testing that it sends the *correct query* to the GraphQL client (again, if I understood your edit correctly; I'm assuming it's a generic GraphQL client). 1/2

Comment: The way you've set it up, your code *requires* something that looks like a GraphQL client - i.e., you *can't* inject something with a different API. So, the stub either does the heavy lifting and hides the complexity of what's actually being tested, or it *doesn't* do that and possibly gives you false positives, if it simply ignores the input and just returns the canned responses (check if your tests catch the error if you send the wrong query). 2/2

Comment: All of what you said is true Filip.  The stub GraphQl client is a well tested in-memory client.  I can easily add data to it.  Am struggling to understand what you would do differently.

Comment: I should also say that I deliberately simplified the setup code in these tests so the focus could be on the evolution of the test cases.  That is the main thing that "feels" wrong for me.  Doing test case #3 felt right - a single Booking Window ending today.  Doing test #4 (many Booking Windows ending today) then made #3 pointless.  Would you iterate the test cases in a different way?

Comment: I was just trying to understand the main points and I didn't really want to suggest anything before you replied. With TDD, what we're trying to test is behavior of the SUT as observable by other code that's in immediate interaction with it. In principle, one could work out the specification of that behavior before one writes any tests, but often we use tests as stepping stones to help us think and design. So your test #3 was a stepping stone - it's fine that you decided to delete it. That's just you deciding to clean up your test code.

Comment: So I wouldn't approach iterating the cases differently, except for occasionally stepping back and doing a little upfront design, just to mix it up. While it's often a helpful strategy, you don't *have* to take tiny steps and decide where to go from there (basically, depth-first search through the design space). You can occasionally step back to reorient yourself.

Comment: Now, what was probably confusing was my train of thought in my original comments - the fact that you're injecting the `client` suggests that there's a contract there as well (are certain methods on the client called as expected) - so you could proceed to write tests for that if you were so inclined (and you may decide it's not worth the effort). What I was trying to understand is if there was a potential design issue there (like perhaps `makeTodaysBookingWindows` mixing business logic and query construction logic) that was the underlying cause of your "feels wrong" remark.

Comment: Very good point, that last one Filip.  The production code is a mix of query construction and business logic.  Its like a Transaction Script I suppose.  Still not sure how I feel about that , but thanks for your assurance on the deleting of test cases.  Others have said the same to me in conversations since posting this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read and re-read this question probably a dozen times trying to figure out what was "wrong" with the TDD approach you took. I honestly don't see anything wrong with what you did. It was all very logical, in fact. I would have started with the same sequence of test cases. The easiest to implement is always a good place to start. Zero bookings. Very easy.

I also would have proceeded to 1 booking being available. Take one more step towards the really complicated logic. And then I would have written exactly the next test, which is to return 2 bookings. The difference is that I would not consider "1 booking" to be an obsolete test case. In my experience, the jump from 1 to "more than 1" can introduce minor bugs. Sure it is just a loop, but that logic is something. The test is written. Keep it if the test executes in milliseconds.

The decision to remove the test returning a single booking is worth considering if the test executes slowly. With respect to test execution time, "slow" means "1 or more seconds".

Both tests took some time to write, but you have already spent that time. The next cost to consider is the time spent executing the test. I would question the value of maintaining both tests if execution times were more than milliseconds. If you measure the execution time of each test in milliseconds, the cost of executing the test is negligible.  Keep both.

Comment: Greg, thanks for taking the time to write such a considerate response.  Yes, my main doubt was around my test case evolution, finding that my 3rd test case can be removed once I have written the 4th.  I wondered if other folks had a smarter approach.  Really reassured to hear your words, and those of others.